# What part of the App Delegate life-cycle is called when an app in the foreground has an out of memory crash?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

Trying to debug a crash that a user is having that isn't showing up in our crash reporting tool or in our log files. Have a theory it might be down to memory pressure, but not sure if `applicationWillTerminate` will be called if iOS kills an app application in the foreground. We write to our log file in `applicationWillTerminate` but it apparently isn't being called during this crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app crashes, no lifecycle method is called reliably. Instead you can create & register a global exception handler which gets invoked in this case:

```
func exceptionHandler(exception: NSException) {
  print("*** UNHANDLED EXCEPTION ***")
  print(exception)
  print("CALL STACK:")
  print(exception.callStackSymbols.joined(separator: "\n"))
}
```

Register this function using `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`, e.g. in your `UIApplicationDelegate.application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`:

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler)
```

Comment: You can set exception breakpoint in debugger with same outcome without any line of code. (Breakpoint tab in  Navigation, + button pin lover left corner), though it is not silverbullet and usually you can't have any suitable result from those exceptions.

Comment: 'course you can. But dropping these few lines in will print every unhandled exception to the console (or the log system, and thus also persist it) which in general is what I want as a starting point for further analysis steps.

Comment: Using this code, I get `A C function pointer can only be formed from a reference to a 'func' or a literal closure` on the `        NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler)
` line

Comment: You must define it as a global function, not as a member method.

Comment: Or, as the error message suggests, you can directly pass in a closure as well: `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler({ print($0) })`

Comment: @dr_bartoYou can setup breakpoint to print to console information you need and continue automatically to achieve same results but without changing the code, you know.

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov 1. Yes, that is of course true; however the OP asked for a solution where a crash can be programmatically processed (e.g. by means of a log system or crash reporting tool), which might be pretty hard do achieve from a breakpoint. 2. Why are you insisting so hard that _your_ way is the only viable solution? Just write an alternative answer describing how this _also_  can be solved, and everybody wins.

Answer (score -1):

System had to trigger `applicationWillTerminate` if it up to kill the app. However you can't be sure how much time you have to before app actually will be killed. Maybe it just not enough time to write the log. Before killing app due to memory consumption system should send memory warning. You can test last one by simulating memory warning on Simulator.  If `applicationWillTerminate` didn't called then want terminated by system and you crash not related directly to memory consumption.